# Macro, new command or new environment for code?

Tags: macros, environments, code

I am using the `listings` package to typeset code. I have defined a custom style using `\lstdefinestyle{verbo}` and then typeset code in a `lstlisting` environment as in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % to retain double quotes in lstlistings
\usepackage{listings}  % to typeset code
\usepackage{upquote}  % to retain single qutoes in lstlistings

\lstdefinestyle{verbo}{  % code typesetting optins
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    language=Python,
    tabsize=1,
    resetmargins=true,
    xleftmargin=0pt,
    frame=single,
    showstringspaces=false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=verbo]
>>> print "Hello World!"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

which produces
[image: Hello World]

I would like to make the LaTeX code more readable by typing the following instead of the `lstlisting` environment but achieving the same result.

```
\begin{code}
>>> print "Hello World!"
\end{code}
```

I tried various things - defining a macro, a new command, a new environment - but all failed. Is there some way to do this?

### Failed Attempts

Below are my failed attempts, all of which result in errors similar to the following

```
! Emergency stop.
<*> \input mwe-code.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

**Macro**

```
\def\code{\begin{lstlisting}[style=verbo]}
\def\ecode{\end{lstlisting}}
  ...    
\code
>>> print "Hello World!"
\ecode
```

**New command**

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\begin{lstlisting}[style=verbo]#1\end{lstlisting}}
  ...
\code{
>>> print "Hello World!"
}
```

**New environment**

```
\newenvironment{code}
{\begin{lstlisting}[style=verbo]}
{\end{lstlisting}}
  ...
\begin{code}
>>> print "Hello World!"
\end{code}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `\lstnewenvironment` just for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % to retain double quotes in lstlistings
\usepackage{listings}  % to typeset code
\usepackage{upquote}  % to retain single qutoes in lstlistings

\lstdefinestyle{verbo}{  % code typesetting optins
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    language=Python,
    tabsize=1,
    resetmargins=true,
    xleftmargin=0pt,
    frame=single,
    showstringspaces=false
}
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]
 {\lstset{style=verbo,#1}}
 {}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
>>> print "Hello World!"
\end{code}

\begin{code}[columns=fullflexible]
>>> print "Hello World!"
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

I added the second one just to show how to add options to the `code` environment.

[image]