# Fancy code environment

Tags: listings, verbatim, minted

I'm writing a small tutorial about LaTeX. So I'd like to insert some code and obtain the result on the right.

I'm almost there. I got the desired output but I'd like something more clear, that is, an easier to type the code.

**Consider the following MWE:**

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\usepackage[section]{minted}

\newminted{tex}{
    bgcolor=bg,
    gobble=1,
    linenos=true,
    firstline=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    fontfamily=courier,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    numberblanklines=false,
    numbersep=3mm,
    xleftmargin=6mm,
    xrightmargin=5mm,
}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\ideal
\setlength{\ideal}{.5\linewidth - 2\fboxsep -2\fboxrule}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{listing}
\begin{texcode}
 \begin{equation}
  \frac{3}{2}=\frac{a}{b}
 \end{equation}
\end{texcode}
\end{listing}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{listing}
\begin{minipage}{\ideal}
\begin{texcode}
 \begin{equation}
  \frac{3}{2}=\frac{a}{b}
 \end{equation}
\end{texcode}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{\ideal}
 \begin{equation}
  \frac{3}{2}=\frac{a}{b}
 \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\caption{title}
\end{listing}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

I'd like to know if this is the right way or if is possible to avoid typing code twice.

I'd like to define an environment `myenv` and then obtain the same as Listing 0.1 simply using

```
\begin{myenv}
 \begin{equation}
  \frac{3}{2}=\frac{a}{b}
 \end{equation}
\end{myenv}
```

And also the caption would be optional. I tried to use `showexpl` but no success until now.

**Edit**

I've just found [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186437/14757) but the result there does not produce the output on the right.

Comment: Are you set on using `minted`? Would you consider using `listings`?

Comment: @Jubobs, I'm using `minted` for the colored code. Only this.

Comment: @Jubobs Even if it's not useful for the OP, you can always post an answer, other people will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you know [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)? It was developed to help formating LaTeX tutorials.

Next code uses default settings, from there you can customize almost everything.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only}
 \begin{equation}
  \frac{3}{2}=\frac{a}{b}
 \end{equation}
\end{tcblisting}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{tcblisting}{listing side text}
 \begin{equation}
  \frac{3}{2}=\frac{a}{b}
 \end{equation}
\end{tcblisting}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll check if it is possible to have colored code like in `minted`. When there are many packages to do almost the same job we get confused. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sigur `tcolorbox` works with `minted` too!.

Answer (score 10):

This merely is a refinement of Konrad's answer that adheres to your specs a bit closer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

% conditional caption (only gets printed if the argument is not empty)
\newcommand\condcaption[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \caption{#1}
  \fi
}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {%
    \listing
      \condcaption{#1}
      \VerbatimEnvironment
        \begin{VerbatimOut}{example.out}%
  }{%
        \end{VerbatimOut}%
        \vspace{1ex}%
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
              \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}%
                \inputminted[
                    resetmargins,
                    bgcolor          = bg,
                    gobble           = 1,
                    linenos          = true,
                    firstline        = 1,
                    firstnumber      = 1,
                    fontfamily       = courier,
                    fontsize         = \footnotesize,
                    numberblanklines = false,
                    numbersep        = 3mm,
                    xleftmargin      = 6mm,
                    xrightmargin     = 5mm,
                  ]{latex}{example.out}%
              \end{minipage}%
        \hspace{0.05\linewidth}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}%
          \input{example.out}%
        \end{minipage}
   \endlisting
}

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}{A simple equation}
 \begin{equation}
  \frac{3}{2}=\frac{a}{b}
 \end{equation}
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}{}
 \begin{equation}
  \frac{3}{2}=1+\frac{1}{2}
 \end{equation}
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I'd just inserted `\begin{listing}\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}` to have the output inside the `listing` environment. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, me too. I'm trying to get captions to work as an optional argument.

Comment: The problem with this kind of env is if I insert a MWE with preamble, the result will be broken since we can not input that code on the right minipage. It works well for piece of codes that are compilable.

Comment: @Sigur You could always comment out the preamble part and let your readers know that they should uncomment it.

Comment: Good idea. Now I'll try to make the example code does not influence on my doc structure. For example, if the example code has a `\section`, I don't want its output following my numbering sections. The same for equation numbering.

Comment: @Sigur Tough one. I guess you'd have to redefine all the commands that modify macros and counters at the global scope.

Comment: Well, for equations, I was thinking to define a `ex.equation` environment and try to replace (maybe using `sed`) the code within `example.out`. Can we insert bash commands inside the environment definitions?

Comment: @Sigur The [`bashful` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bashful) may be of interest.

Comment: Your code above is producing `! FancyVerb Error:  Extraneous input \begin {equation} between \begin{myenv}[<key=value>] and line end`. If I use `myenv` only once, no problem.

Comment: @Sigur The error disappears if you make sure that `\begin{myenv}` is followed by an empty `[]`. Surely, that could be made more robust, though...

Comment: It is not too optional. It is a kind of *opitionatory* (mandatory option lol). Nice!

Comment: @Sigur I guess making the caption a mandatory argument (which you can leave empty) makes more sense. See my last edit.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [source code of minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/0d9edaf9774ed3d70335eaf060b44f3fa996f77e/source/minted.dtx#L99-L112), it does the exact same thing to typeset its examples in the documentation.

Here’s the relevant part:

```
\newenvironment{example}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
   \begin{VerbatimOut}[gobble=3]{example.out}}
  {\end{VerbatimOut}%
   \vspace{1ex}%
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
   \fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}%
     \inputminted[resetmargins]{latex}{example.out}%
   \end{minipage}%
   \hspace{0.05\linewidth}%
   \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}%
     \input{example.out}%
   \end{minipage}%
   \vspace{1ex}}}
```

It uses two side-by-side `minipage`s to put the example code and output adjacently. Internally, `\VerbatimOut` is used to store the example code, verbatim, in a temporary file which is then passed to `minted` for pretty-printing (left side) and `\input`ted directly for typesetting (on the right side).

Comment: Ow, thanks so much for this nice piece of code. I'll try to adapt it and make some tests.